# "if: No catch for tag: emacs-version-changed, nil" when trying to insert keyboard macro

Tags: keyboard-macros

I'm trying to define a keyboard macro that will double space a region of text. After I highlighted the region of text that I want to double space, I tried both `evil-record-macro` and `kmacro-start-macro` to record the macro (I believe they do the same thing).

I then tried `edit-kbd-macro` to make sure that I defined the macro properly. The macro editing code was displayed as the following:

```
SPC b -         ;; doom/toggle-narrow-buffer
<escape>        ;; evil-force-normal-state
:           ;; evil-ex
%           ;; evil-jump-item
s           ;; evil-snipe-s
/           ;; +default/search-buffer
\           ;; vundo
n           ;; evil-ex-search-next
/           ;; +default/search-buffer
\           ;; vundo
n           ;; evil-ex-search-next
\           ;; vundo
n           ;; evil-ex-search-next
/           ;; +default/search-buffer
g <return>
SPC b -         ;; doom/toggle-narrow-buffer
```

And I also tried defining the macro as the following (which does the same exact thing, just will the traditional `query-replace` instead of evil-mode search and replace shown previously):

```
SPC b -         ;; doom/toggle-narrow-buffer
SPC e q         ;; query-replace
C-q         ;; quoted-insert
LFD         ;; evil-window-increase-height
RET         ;; apropos-follow
C-q         ;; quoted-insert
LFD         ;; evil-window-increase-height
C-q         ;; quoted-insert
LFD         ;; evil-window-increase-height
RET         ;; apropos-follow
!           ;; evil-shell-command
SPC b -         ;; doom/toggle-narrow-buffer
```

After I finished defining and editing the macro both times, `call-last-kbd-macro` was able to execute the macro and have it do exactly what I wanted both times. I was satisfied with the behavior, so I executed `name-last-kbd-macro` to give the Macro a name. Next, I tried `insert-kbd-macro` to insert the Elisp code into my `config.el` (or init.el for regular Emacs users), but the minibuffer displayed: `if: No catch for tag: emacs-version-changed, nil`. I'm using Emacs 28.1, Doom core v3.0.0-dev, and Doom modules v22.07.0-dev.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. From what I've researched, the reason why this error was thrown is because elisp byte-code is not guaranteed to work across Emacs versions. But I don't know why this would be the case because I can't even figure out how to see what the corresponding elisp code is, whether it's defined both ways.

Also, does the commented text following each line in the macro definitions have anything to do with this problem? I don't think it should, but a lot of this commented text is only showing the keybindings that I have configured for each of those Emacs keys, if I weren't using them inside a search-and-replace command.

Comment: I think before you can insert the macro, you have to [save and name it](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html) (i.e. use `C-x C-k n`) first.

Comment: @dalanicolai Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that I tried that too. It still doesn't work, even after naming the macro. I've edited the post to include this information.

Comment: Okay, then maybe try `toggle-debug-on-error`, [debug-on-message](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html), or edebugging `insert-kbd-macro`...

Comment: Okay, I did that. I'm not sure what the text below means, though:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (no-catch emacs-version-changed nil)
  throw(emacs-version-changed nil)
  (if (equal (emacs-version) "GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0)\n of 2022-05-30") nil (throw 'emacs-version-changed nil))
  (unless (equal (emacs-version) "GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0)\n of 2022-05-30") (throw 'emacs-version-changed nil))
byte-code("\300\301\302\303\304E\305BB!\207" [eval unless equal ...

Comment: I am also not sure. Can you try `M-x load-library` `kmacro`, and then try to insert the macro? Because, to me, it looks like something might be wrong with the compiled version of `kmacro.elc` (i.e. like it was compiled with the wrong Emacs version)

Comment: I think that is a good guess about why the macro won't insert. I just tried loading the kmacro library, and Emacs still returned the same result when I tried to insert the macro: `No catch for tag: emacs-version-changed, nil`.

Comment: Maybe you can try `M-: (find-library-name "kmacro.elc")`, note the version in the path, and then compare to `M-x emacs-version`. If that gives no clue, then I guess I don't have any other ideas (except for reinstalling Emacs). It could be caused by something completely different also... I am just guessing...

Comment: After running `find-library "kmacro.elc"`, the mini-buffer returned: `Can't find library: kmacro`.

Comment: That doesn't sound good. How did you install Emacs? Maybe try reinstalling Emacs...

Comment: I believe I added the ppa:kelleyk/emacs repository (on Linux Mint), and installed emacs 28.1. And I cloned doom-emacs from: https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs. Emacs is saying that `insert-kbd-macro` is an interactive and byte-compiled function without a source file. I'm not sure why all the other commands I called were able to work, while kmacro.elc is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Maybe try after loading [this file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/kmacro.el?h=emacs-28.1.91&id=e6af4968f947a3e536fbd80e74fea44ca18e22ac).

Comment: Even after evaluating lisp code for loading the file, Emacs still says that `insert-kbd-macro` does not have a source file, and the `insert-kbd-macro` still prints `if: No catch for tag: emacs-version-changed, nil`...  I guess re-installing Emacs is the only thing left that I could try, but that seems like a lot of work and even intimidating for me.

Comment: Maybe first just remove that Emacs installed from the distro (something like `apt remove emacs28`, and see if there is still another Emacs available (from the linux mint standard repo, i.e. `apt install emacs`).